# Maximize efficiency of SQL SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Assum that we have a vary large table. for example - 3000 rows of data.
And we need to select all the rows that thire field `status < 4`.
We know that the relevance rows will be maximum from 2 months ago (of curse that each row has a date column).

**does this query is the most efficient ??**

```
SELECT * FROM database.tableName WHERE status<4 

AND DATE< '".date()-5259486."' ;
```

*(date() - php , 5259486 - two months.)...*

Comment: How are your dates stored?

Comment: Is there a way to migrate your old records to another table? It's a good pratice. Another good tip: create a View for this select statement.

Comment: 3000 rows is not a very large table! For more efficiency only list the columns you need, [don't use SELECT *](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list), also consider creating an index on Date and Status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're storing dates as `DATETIME`, you could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM database.tableName
WHERE status < 4
  AND DATE < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTHS)
```

Also, for optimizing search queries you could use `EXPLAIN` ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html ) like this:

```
EXPLAIN [your SELECT statement]
```

Another point where you can tweak response times is by carefully placing appropriate indexes.

Indexes are used to find rows with specific column values quickly. Without an index, MySQL must begin with the first row and then read through the entire table to find the relevant rows. The larger the table, the more this costs. If the table has an index for the columns in question, MySQL can quickly determine the position to seek to in the middle of the data file without having to look at all the data.

Here are some explanations & tutorials on MySQL indexes:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

However, keep in mind that using TIMESTAMP instead of DATETIME is more efficient; the former is 4 bytes; the latter is 8. They hold equivalent information (except for timezone issues).

Comment: "you can tweak response times is by carefully placing appropriate indexes." - what does indexes do and how can I place them?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a couple of tutorials for MySQL Indexes.

Answer (score 0):

3,000 rows of data is not large for a database.  In fact, it is on the *small* side.

The query:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM database.tableName
 WHERE status < 4 ;
```

Should run pretty quickly on 3,000 rows, unless each row is very, very large (say 10k).  You can always put an index on `status` to make it run faster.

The query suggested by cassi.iup makes more sense:

```
SELECT *
FROM database.tableName
WHERE status < 4 AND DATE < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTHS);
```

It will perform better with a composite index on `status, date`.  My question is:  do you want all rows with a status of 4 or do you want all rows with a status of 4 in the past two months?  In the first case, you would have to continually change the query.  You would be better off with:

```
SELECT *
FROM database.tableName
WHERE status < 4 AND DATE < date('2013-06-19');
```

(as of the date when I am writing this.)

Comment: Thenk you for your answer. Can you explain me the "indexing" method that you talk about? Never used it before...

Comment: @user2216190 . . . You can start by reading the documentation on them, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html.